# Animation delay causes animation to be out of sync with the view layout in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

Using a delayed animation on an HStack causes the animation to become out of sync with the view layout. This looks like very simple SwiftUI code.

Without the animation `.delay()`, everything works fine.

If `showView` is toggled after the animation has finished, then it works fine.

If `showView` is toggled when the animation is almost finished, then it will start being out of sync until the animation finishes completely.

```swift
// ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showView = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                if showView {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
            }
            .animation(.default.delay(1), value: showView) // .delay() here causes the issues
            
            Button("Toggle Text") {
                showView.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image: AnimationDelay]

This happens on the current iOS version (simulator iOS 17.2 and device iOS 17.3.1) and latest Xcode (15.2) at the time of the writing.

Comment: How do you reproduce this? When do you have to press the button? I pressed the button many times and it worked correctly, though I did run it on the simulator instead of previews. Did you try running it on the simulator too?

Comment: You can reproduce it by pressing the button when the animation is almost finished. That makes it out of sync. I tried it on the simulator as well, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also could reproduce the bug.
And I could solve it using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showView = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                if showView {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
            }
            .animation(.default, value: showView)
            
            Button("Toggle Text") {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    showView.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```